# How to install oracle in mac using docker

Tags: oracle, macos, docker

I am trying to install oracle in macos using docker. I am new to docker and tried to install oracle using the containers present in the oracle docker images github like https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleDatabase

```sh
docker run -p 1521:1521 -p 5500:5500 oracle/database:12.1.0.2-ee

docker run --shm-size=1g -p 1521:1521 -p 8080:8080 oracle/database:11.2.0.2-xe

./buildDockerImage.sh -v 12.1.0.2
```

But none of the commands worked for me. It said:

> ```
> Unable to find image 'oracle/database:11.2.0.2-xe' locally
> bash: pwmake: command not found
> ```

Can I install these containers only in linux?

Answer (score 0):

They've tried [here](http://bobyakov.org/2014/02/01/oracle-virtualbox-docker-osx/) to do what you want, but they state that

> The easiest way to run an Oracle database on OS X is to use a [preconfigured virtual machine](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/databaseappdev-vm-161299.html).
>
> ## Install VirtualBox and import the machine.

You must then download that VM from Oracle and run it on your VirtualBox. I advise you make a backup copy of the VM when you are happy with how its configure. Then when you've broke it by *playing a little too hard*, you can revert to the "good working" state.

Comment: Its a 2014 post. So many things have changed since. Said that I am also trying to use docker for oracle xe in my mac pro. Lets see!